# set a toggle tab active when open the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I've made 3 toggle tabs which will open when clicked on button. but I want to set one of these tabs active so that when the page is loaded it will be open by default, and then by clicking on each button the other contents will be show.
sorry for the bad english
it's like this:

html:

```
    <button href="#Teachers" class="tablinks" onclick="openContent(event, 'Teachers')" > برای مدرسین</button>
    <button href="#Users" class="tablinks" onclick="openContent(event, 'Users')">برای کاربران</button>
    <button href="#Institutes" class="tablinks" onclick="openContent(event, 'Institutes')">برای آموزشگاه ها</button>
```

and js :

```
function openContent(evt, userName) {
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  document.getElementById(userName).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
```

it's like this when you open the page :
[image]

and like this when you click on each button, and I want the first button to be active when I open the page:

[image]

Comment: I had to set the display of first button to "block" in css and add the active class in html

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve above is calling the `openContent()` function onload of your page and then checking if the `evt.currentTarget` is not undefined depending on this show your content .

***Demo Code*** :

```js
openContent("","Teachers");//call function

function openContent(evt, userName) {
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  document.getElementById(userName).style.display = "block";
  //check if target is undefined
  if (evt.currentTarget != undefined) {
    evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
  } else {
  //add activeclass to first button 
    document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks")[0].className += " active";
  }
}
```

```css
.tabcontent {
  display: none;
}

.active {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<button href="#Teachers" class="tablinks" onclick="openContent(event, 'Teachers')"> برای مدرسین</button>
<button href="#Users" class="tablinks" onclick="openContent(event, 'Users')">برای کاربران</button>
<button href="#Institutes" class="tablinks" onclick="openContent(event, 'Institutes')">برای آموزشگاه ها</button>

<div id="Teachers" class="tabcontent">Something</div>
<div id="Users" class="tabcontent">Something1</div>
<div id="Institutes" class="tabcontent">Something2</div>
```